# TFS Agent Pool, No agent found in pool PublishPool which satisfies the specified demands: msbuild visualstudio Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.95.0

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

when i am try to build my project it gives me error that says

> No agent found in pool PublishPool which satisfies the specified demands: msbuild visualstudio Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0

my agent version is 2.136.1 to based on Capabilities section but i don't understand that why my project wants older version to build and i couldn't find how to update my project's demanding version to my agent version. 
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem wasn't the version of my agent, i found out later that gtVersion means that greater than so there was no error there error was my agent hasn't msbuild and visualstudio. When i add them to demands section problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Visual Studio on your agent machine, and restart your agent service.